# Is there a component like DatePicker for selecting String values?

Tags: android, components

I want the user to be able to select from a list of string values (about 25 in all) and like the idea of using the DatePicker style component to do it. However, all I can find is the spinner which is a drop down box and my selection list is just a little too big for it. Is there a component like DatePicker I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Documentation: [Adding a List to AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList).

Answer (score 2):

there is no such component in Android. I have an idea.

lets go with an `AlertDialog` with the combination of `ListView` at the view level. To do that create  an AlertDialog and then create a view having listview that contains 25 string elements in connected by a `SimpleAdapter`. Once you done with the listview and adapter stuff, come to the `Alertdialog` and use `setView()` of `AlertDialog.Builder`.